# What happened to the calendarserver package for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, calendar

I want to install [Darwin Calendar Server](https://www.calendarserver.org/QuickStart.html) on Ubuntu 20.04. In the past (Bionic), this could be done with

```
sudo apt install calendarserver
```

It looks like it still is in the Debian repositories: https://wiki.debian.org/CalendarServer

Has it changed names? Should I use a PPA or build it from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu it is [still available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/calendarserver) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Then according to Debian Package tracker it [was removed](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/calendarserver):

> **package is gone**
>
> This package is not in any development repository. This probably means that the package has been removed (or has been renamed). Thus the information here is of little interest ... the package is going to disappear unless someone takes it over and reintroduces it.

> [2020-03-07] Removed 9.2+dfsg-1 from unstable (Debian FTP Masters)

and as per https://tracker.debian.org/news/1107199/removed-92dfsg-1-from-unstable/

> **Reason**
>
> RoQA; Upstream Dead; Unmaintained; Affected by Python2 Removal

Comment: That "affected by Python2 removal" bit is probably the answer why the package is not available...